# Scavenging Xenon

Tags: experimental-chemistry

This may well be off topic - if so I will remove it or the mods can.

We will be using a good few litres of Xenon by running it through a new analytical instrument. Given it's price (at a guess, around $15 per litre at STP) is there any standard method of recycling it? I really do not want to vent it to atmosphere.

Comment: Googling for 'xenon recycling system' comes up with multiple hits from several different areas (EUV litho systems, plasma processing, human anesthesia), so it is clearly possible. BOC Edwards appears to market (or did market) a turnkey recycling system. Whether it is worth it in your setup is a question only you can answer.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm starting to think "balloons"!

Comment: What is the Xe used for (carrier gas?), and how pure does it have to be? What else is going through the system? For example, you might get away with a LN2-cooled sorption pump to trap the Xenon, then every once in a while purge it through perhaps an appropriate molecular sieve?

Comment: @JonCuster We are going to measure the speed of sound in Xenon as part of a calibration test. I'm starting to think it might be too expensive. Flow is 100 ccm ( $1.50 per minute for several hours)

Comment: I would suggest SF6 but I'm not sure it is any cheaper. Do you have to flow it, or backfill and valve off?

Comment: @JonCuster I was going to say "flow" but I think maybe just filling the apparatus might be sufficient. Esp given the budget. We use flow as part of a continuous measurement process where we expect composition to change, but if it is a pure gas maybe no need to flow.